# Was the Nusach Sefaradi used in the Ashkenazi communities?

Tags: ashkenazi, nusach-sefard

As far as we know, the Nusach Sefaradi penetrated the Ashkenazi through the Hasidim, among whom it became Sefard. Although, in fact, most of its varieties are 80% identical to Sefardai, and its descendant can be considered a regional variety of this nusach.

Were there cases before the Hasidim? Or some variants similar to Sefaradi.

Comment: Sephardi and Mizrahi Jews were migrating to Germany, Poland, and Southeastern Europe as early as the 1200's. It would be hard to guess whether their siddurim were influential with existing local Communities ot not 
 https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/sephardic-and-mizrahi-jews-in-ashkenazic-lands/

Comment: @יהושע they probably didn't bring many siddurim pre-printing press, but just used whatever was there when they showed up. Adapting to local minhagim used to be organic.

Comment: The "Nusah Sfard" is not monolithic, and there are many sub-varieties. Some leaning more towards the Ashkenazi nusah and some more towards the Sefaradi. What is the basis of your claim that "most of its varieties are 80% identical to Sefardai, and its descendant can be considered a regional variety of this nusach"?

Comment: If anything, it seems to me that the substrate for hassidic ‘nusach sefard’ is nusach polin (eastern nusach ashkenaz), with some features of nusach edot hamizrach bolted on, due to kabbalistic considerations. Such that I would consider it a descendant of classical nusach ashkenaz, rather than edot hamizrach.

Comment: @JoelK In my memory, in the Nusach Chabad (Siddur Tehilat Ha-Shem), the order of Pesukei de-Zimra almost coincided with that in the Nusach Edot ha-Mizrach (Siddur of Shlomo ben David). And in general, the liturgy almost completely coincided there. But there are serious differences with Nusah Ashkenaz (Siddur Shaarei Tefilah).

Comment: @Dankl-FranlbarUri-Hirschl Yes. That is one obvious change that was made in line with Edot Hamizrach - moving hodu (and the extra psalms on shabbat) before baruch sheamar. But if you focus on the actual texts of the blessings (surrounding the shema and comprising the amidah) themselves, as well as tachanun, avinu malkeinu, selichot and piyutim in general, you should notice the nusach ashkenaz substrate fairly clearly